# Perturbation theory for a symetric rank-one update

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, perturbation-theory

I know perturbation theory of the eigenspectrum/singular value decompostion of a symetric matrix $A$ under a symetric perturbation $E$, that besides being symetric has no other structure.

Is there some theory about perturbations of the form $A' = A + \lambda \cdot vv'$?

Comment: There are nice things you can say about the singular values, and there are theorems about "updating" the inverse

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Can you provide some references please?

Comment: See the [Sherman Morrison formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula) for the bit about inverses. I think that Bhatia's Matrix Analysis has all the inequalities for this kind of thing